# Sitecore Package Created on One Version and Imported to a Different Version

Tags: packages

If I create a Sitecore package for some Dictionary items with Sitecore 7.5, can I import the package to a site running on Sitecore 8.1 Update 3?

Comment: Can you give more details of the Dictionary items? Are you using Sitecore Dictionary or these items are user defined templates? Either way, as Gatogordo suggested, go for it.But make sure to backup your target database.

Comment: Do not see why you cannot do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about following templates (not any custom that I am not aware of):

**Dictionary folder**: `{267D9AC7-5D85-4E9D-AF89-99AB296CC218}`

**Dictionary entry**: `{6D1CD897-1936-4A3A-A511-289A94C2A7B1}`

Then the answer is **YES**.

In one open source module we haven't change many dictionary items for a long time (5 years already) and everything is fine..

Sitecore Package structure wasn't changed since **Sitecore 7.5**  for sure so I don't see any contraindications.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is possible to import packages from lower versions. An issue could be if you have a field type that was changed, but that should not be the case for dictionary items. So I would go for it.